# Json Returning lowercase when should be Pascal Case

Tags: c#, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using .net core 3.1 and I have set up in accordance with the Microsoft article at the following address a default contactor but when I look inside postman it's still showing lower case JSON responses.

I am using Telerik's kendo ui grid which expects Pascal case now the object is correctly delivered so that leaves me completely stuck as to what may be going wrong.

Telerik Grid  https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/grid/index

Docs :  https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)    {
   services.AddControllers();
   services.Configure<ConnectionStringConfig>(Configuration);

   services.AddHttpClient("externalservice", c =>    {
            // Assume this is an "external" service which requires an API KEY
            c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/");
   });
   services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Api For RoundTable A Complete ERP for 
warehouse managment", Version = "v1" });
        });

        services
            .AddControllersWithViews()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
            // Maintain property names during serialization. See:
            // https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());

}
```

My controller in my api is just fetching from sql server.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> ReadStock([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
 {
         List<Stock> _result = new List<Stock>();
        _result =await  apiClient.GetStockFromApi();
         object test  = Json(_result);
        return Json(_result);

}
```

However, when I checked postman the result is still comming in lower case hence

[image]

The following is my getstock api call.

```
 public async Task<List<Stock>> GetStockFromApi(){
        List<Stock> _result = new List<Stock>();

        var uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constants.GetALlStock, string.Empty));

        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var byteArray = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync(); 

            var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            _result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Stock>>(content);
        }

        return _result.ToList();
    }
```

**Update**
Imanaged to get it to pascal case but the grid is still returning no data.

Comment: If the grid is the problem you should share how you configure grid. And did you check the network tab? Does your grid make a request to `GetStockFromApi` method.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I had to do apparently it defaults to camel case however I must stress I did not have to do this before version 3.0.

https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194

This is the only thing that worked place it in your startup.cs after

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.Configure<ConnectionStringConfig>(Configuration);

    services.AddHttpClient("externalservice", c =>
    {
        // Assume this is an "external" service which requires an API KEY
        c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/");
    });
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>

    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Api For RoundTable A Complete ERP for warehouse managment", Version = "v1" });
    });

    services
        .AddControllersWithViews()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

    services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions =>
        {
            jsonOptions.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
        })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
}
```

In Particular this line here

> services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions =>    {
>           jsonOptions.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;    })    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

When I did this my JSON was in proper case although data did not show I had to use Telerik inbuilt dataset to return my data in correct data form for kendo UI.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> ReadStock([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
 {
            List<Stock> _result = new List<Stock>();
            _result =await  apiClient.GetStockFromApi();                        
            return Json(_result.ToDataSourceResult(request));             
 }
```